# Dirichlet's principle- task.

Tags: combinatorics

Given is set $S$ where $|S| = n > 1 $ and his subsets $M_1, ..., M_{n+1}$ such that $M_i \neq M_j, i \neq j $ Using Dirichlet's principle prove that exists $A, B$ where $A,B \subset \{1,...,n+1\} $ such that $$\bigcup_{k\in A} M_k = \bigcup_{k\in A} M_k  $$

Comment: I suppose that the second union is for $k \in B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that for every $A,B \subset \{1,...,n+1\}$ which are different you nave
$$ \bigcup_{k \in A} M_k \neq \bigcup_{k \in B} M_k$$
Thus, the function 
$$ A \mapsto \bigcup_{k \in A}M_k$$
is injective from the set of non void parts of $\{1,...,n+1\}$ to the set of nonvoid parts of $S$. But this is not possible, since there are $2^{n+1}-1$ non void subsets $\{1,...,n+1\}$ and there are only $2^n-1$ non void subsets of $S$.

Terefore, there must be some $A$ and $B$ such that there is equality.